# Kubernetes deploying kafka service for providing external service

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm trying to learn how to use kubernetes to deploy a kafka service cluster on docker with this tutorial: https://learnk8s.io/kafka-ha-kubernetes.

How can I change the kafka.yaml to expose the kafka service to the outside of the cluster?

I tried to change the service type from ClusterIP to NodePort or LoadBalancer according to the tips from chatGPT, but I don't know how to set the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS?

For example, I tried to change the service type to the `LoadBalancer` mode:

```
type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: '9092'
      port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9092
...
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://<EXTERNAL_IP>:30092
```

or the `NodePort` mode:

```
type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: '9092'
      port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30092
...
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://<EXTERNAL_IP>:30092
```

But when I tried to tcpping the IP with port 30092, the connection seems refused. And when I tried to use `netestat -nat | grep 30092/9092`, there's no results as well.

Comment: Start here - https://strimzi.io/